# La conversión especificada de un tipo 'System.Int32' materializado al tipo 'System.String' no es válida

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

He creado un aplicativo web MVC con entity framework.
La aplicación consiste en un inventario de alimentación, donde tengo un inicio de sesión, un apartado para ingresos, uno para salidas y uno para administrar los productos y proveedores.

Tengo una base de datos llamada BD_Inventario, en la que tengo una tabla proveedor. Al momento de la ejecución del aplicativo, no hay problemas al inicia sesión, pero al momento de ingresar a el detalle de los proveedores me sale el siguiente error:

```
The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid.
```

tengo claro que es algo relacionado al tipo de dato del campo documento (el cual es la clave primaria de la tabla proveedor), el tipo de dato en sql es int, y al crear el entity framework, lo crea como string.

al momento de ingresar a el campo para administrar proveedores, el aplicativo deja de funcionar y me sale el error de la imagen, el cual lo marca en el controlador de proveedores en la línea 33:

```
 return View(pro.ToList());
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

adjunto mi modelo proveedor y el controlador donde se marca el error.
Gracias de antemano.

Modelo

```
`
namespace Inventario_Alimentacion.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Proveedor
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", 
        "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Proveedor()
        {
            this.Temporal = new HashSet<Temporal>();
        }

        public string Prov_Docum { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> fk_Ciudad { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> fk_TipoDocum { get; set; }
        public string Prov_Nombre { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Prov_Telefono { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Prov_Celular { get; set; }
        public string Prov_Email { get; set; }
        public string Prov_Direccion { get; set; }
        public string Prov_Fax { get; set; }
        public string Prov_ActiEcono { get; set; }

        public virtual Ciudad Ciudad { get; set; }
        public virtual Tipo_Documento Tipo_Documento { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", 
        "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Temporal> Temporal { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`
controller

```
 using System;//this
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.Entity;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Net;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Mvc;
 using Inventario_Alimentacion.Filters;
 using Inventario_Alimentacion.Models;

 namespace Inventario_Alimentacion.Controllers
 {
 public class ProveedorsController : Controller
 {
     private BD_InventarioEntities db = new BD_InventarioEntities();
     // GET: Proveedors
     [AuthorizeUser(idOperacion: 2)]
     public ActionResult BusquedaFilter(String Nombre, string Id)
     {
        
         var pro = from s in db.Proveedor select s;
         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Nombre))
         {
             pro = pro.Where(J => J.Prov_Nombre.Contains(Nombre));
         }

         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Id))
         {
             return View(pro.Where(x => x.Prov_Docum == Id));   
         }
         return View(pro.ToList());
     }

     // GET: Proveedors/Details/5
     public ActionResult Details(string id)
     {
         if (id == null)
         {
             return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
         }
         Proveedor proveedor = db.Proveedor.Find(id);
         if (proveedor == null)
         {
             return HttpNotFound();
         }
         return View(proveedor);
     }

     // GET: Proveedors/Create
     public ActionResult Create()
     { 
         LlenarLista();
         return View();
         
     }
     public ActionResult LlenarLista()
     {
         using (BD_InventarioEntities db2 = new BD_InventarioEntities())
         {

             List<Tipo_Documento> Lista = new List<Tipo_Documento>();
             Lista = db2.Tipo_Documento.ToList();
             ViewBag.ListaDocumentos = Lista;

             List<Ciudad> Lista2 = new List<Ciudad>();
             Lista2 = db2.Ciudad.ToList();
             ViewBag.ListaCiudades = Lista2;

         }
         return View();

         
     }
     // crear drop down list de tipos de cedula
    

     // POST: Proveedors/Create
     // Para protegerse de ataques de publicación excesiva, habilite las propiedades                     
     específicas a las que desea enlazarse. Para obtener 
     // más información vea https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
     [HttpPost]
     [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
     public ActionResult Create(int fk_TipoDocum,int? fk_Ciudad,String Prov_Docum,String 
     Prov_Nombre,int?  Prov_Telefono,int? Prov_Celular, String Prov_Email, String 
     Prov_Direccion, String Prov_Fax, String Prov_ActiEcono)
     {
         if (!fk_TipoDocum.Equals(null) && !fk_Ciudad.Equals(null) && 
         !Prov_Docum.Equals(null) && !Prov_Nombre.Equals(null) && 
         !Prov_Telefono.Equals(null) &&
                   !Prov_Celular.Equals(null) && !Prov_Email.Equals(null) && 
                   !Prov_Direccion.Equals(null) && !Prov_Fax.Equals(null) && 
                   !Prov_ActiEcono.Equals(null))
         {
             var obj = from s in db.Proveedor select s;
             obj = obj.Where(J => J.Prov_Docum == Prov_Docum);
             if (!obj.Any()) //convierte el comando en bolleano
             {
                 db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec spCrearProveedor @Prov_Docum, 
                   @fk_Ciudad , @fk_TipoDocum,@Prov_Nombre, @Prov_Telefono, 
                   @Prov_Celular, @Prov_Email, @Prov_Direccion, @Prov_Fax, 
                   @Prov_ActiEcono",
                     new SqlParameter("@Prov_Docum", Prov_Docum),new 
                     SqlParameter("@fk_Ciudad", fk_Ciudad),
                     new SqlParameter("@fk_TipoDocum", fk_TipoDocum),new 
                     SqlParameter("@Prov_Nombre", Prov_Nombre),
                     new SqlParameter("@Prov_Telefono", Prov_Telefono),new 
                     SqlParameter("@Prov_Celular", Prov_Celular),
                     new SqlParameter("@Prov_Email", Prov_Email), new 
                     SqlParameter("@Prov_Direccion", Prov_Direccion),
                     new SqlParameter("@Prov_Fax", Prov_Fax), new 
                     SqlParameter("@Prov_ActiEcono", Prov_ActiEcono));

                 return RedirectToAction("BusquedaFilter");
             } else
             {
                 return RedirectToAction("BusquedaFilter");
             }
         }

         return RedirectToAction("BusquedaFilter");
     }

     // GET: Proveedors/Edit/5
     public ActionResult Edit(string id)
     {
         LlenarLista();  
         if (id == null)
         {
             return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
         }
         Proveedor proveedor = db.Proveedor.Find(id);
         if (proveedor == null)
         {
             return HttpNotFound();
         }
         return View(proveedor);
     }

     // POST: Proveedors/Edit/5
     // Para protegerse de ataques de publicación excesiva, habilite las propiedades 
     específicas a las que desea enlazarse. Para obtener 
     // más información vea https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
     [HttpPost]
     [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
     //public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = 
     "fk_TipoDocum, fk_Ciudad, Prov_Docum, Prov_Nombre, Prov_Telefono, Prov_Celular, 
     Prov_Email, Prov_Direccion, Prov_Fax, Prov_ActiEcono")] Proveedor proveedor)
     public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Prov_Docum, fk_Ciudad, fk_TipoDocum, 
     Prov_Nombre, Prov_Telefono, Prov_Celular, Prov_Email, ProvDireccion, Prov_Fax, 
     Prov_ActiEcono")]Proveedor proveedor)
     {
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
             db.Entry(proveedor).State = EntityState.Modified;
             db.SaveChanges();
             return RedirectToAction("BusquedaFilter");
         }
            //LlenarLista();
            return View(proveedor);
         }

        // GET: Proveedors/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                 return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Proveedor proveedor = db.Proveedor.Find(id);
            if (proveedor == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(proveedor);
        }

        // POST: Proveedors/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
        {

            var obj = from s in db.Detalle_Entrada select s;
            obj = obj.Where(J => J.fk_Proveedor ==id);
            if (!obj.Any()) //convierte el comando en bolleano
            {
                Proveedor proveedor = db.Proveedor.Find(id);
                db.Proveedor.Remove(proveedor);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("BusquedaFilter");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Delete");

            }
         
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                    db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Revisa que en la definicion de tu tabla tengas los mismos tipos de dato que en tu modelo, el error lo lanza cuando tiene que retornar la query.

Comment: En mi base de datos lo declare como int, pero al crear los modelos, se genera como string. he intentado cambiando el tipo de dato del modelo, pero me saca un error que dice que los tipos de dato no coinciden.

Comment: Con que creas el modelo? El problema va a persistir mientras los tipos de datos sean diferentes.

Comment: se crean automáticamente cuando creo el entity framework